# How to specify the services in the block pedService based on the agent's current level?

Tags: anylogic

I am currently using Anylogic 8 to create a simulation model of the elevator. I find a useful tutorial from this blog: https://elc.github.io/blog/images/elevator-simulation/student-behavior.jpg.

I am particularly interested in the implementation of the `waitFloorX` blocks in the picture [logic flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f1yF.png) as it chooses its own service with line based on the agent's current level. How could I specify this dynamic attribute for my pedService block. In Anylogic, this attribute is shown to be a static value ([services attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGKS4.png)
). Therefore, I am not sure whether can I write a line of code to retrieve the object of services I want.

I tried to write one line of code to retrieve the service object that I want:

```
this.getLevel().getServices().get(0)
```

It failed to run the simulation. I am not sure it is possible for static value in this case.

Thanks in advance!